# Absolute values of height and width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, screen

I have a Wpf application and i'd like that all the windows be full screen and centred. I add this instruction in every constructor:

```
WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

In my own PC it's works. but in other it didn't because of the fixed values.

```
<Window x:Class="IHM.Authentification"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="" Height="803" Width="1380px" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#FFE8EEF3" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
```

I'd like that the values of the height and width will be dynamic and independent of the dimensions of the PC's screen.

So how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the fixed values and add

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

to remove constructor

```
<Window x:Class="IHM.Authentification"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Title="" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#FFE8EEF3" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None"
 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the WindowState="Maximized" will do